# Swapping Alt and Super keys with different Keyboard Layouts in 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, shortcut-keys, bluetooth, keyboard-layout

I have two keyboards I use regularly, one PC layout and one Mac layout. I would like the Alt and Super keys in the same position on each but they are reversed. I don't mind switching them manually when moving between them but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this.  Changing between Keyboard Layouts "English (US)" and "English (Macintosh)" makes no difference to either keyboards Alt/Super key positions.

It also appears as if the method previously available has been removed (an option in the System>Preferences>Keyboard). That leaves me with scripting a solution.  Am I missing something?

I've been looking for an answer to this for hours.  I have no problem scripting and will create one right now but it seems like this functionality should be available through the GUI and may have been once.

(I'm using a Kinesis Freestyle2 Blue for Mac and Lenovo P50 with Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Perhaps one of the "Typing" options in gnome-tweak-tool can accomplish this?

Comment: Using gnome-tweak-tool did actually work.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing, you should answer your own question with what options you used so anyone who finds this question has a complete answer.

Comment: Used the following selection in the gnome-tweak-tool: Typing -> Alt/Win key behavior -> Alt is swapped with Win